# Cannot get openapi-generator-cli version-manager list

Tags: node.js, npm, openapi-generator-cli

I have installed openapi-generator-cli by `yarn global add @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli`

I used to get a list of versions of Open API generator after typing a command:

```
npx openapi-generator-cli version-manager list
```

Now I'm getting a following error

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/openapi-generator-cli - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'openapi-generator-cli@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have removed `@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli` which was added by `yarn` and I've readded it by

```
npm install @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli -g
```

Comment: I also needed to downgrade node from 19.4.0 to 16.19.0 because I was getting another error